# Whatsapp ACTION_SEND Force

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I need to place a button on my app in order to share a text and url only with another application: Whatsapp.

I'm trying this code but it doesn't work. I have tried it many ways, but in theory it should just need `waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");` to ensure that only this app would be executed when the button is pressed and the intent is called.

Is there a way using URI or smth?
Greetings
David

```
    public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        if (waIntent != null) {
            waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
        } 

    }
```

Comment: what do you want to share URL or URI

Answer (score 0):

To share with Whatsapp use the following code

```
                   Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                   whatsappIntent.setType("image/*");

                   whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text here");
                   whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);               
                   whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");        
                   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(whatsappIntent, "Your Awesome Text and Pic..."));
```